# com_error: Oulook.Application

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to save  Outlook email as msg file to a folder using Python.
The line of code is giving me the following error: 
com_error: (-2147467260, 'Operation aborted', None, None).

How can I resolve the issue?

My code:

```
import win32com.client
Path = "dir\\folder"
outlook = win32com.client.Dispatch.("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace"MAPI")
inbox = outlook.Folders(Folder1Folders(Folder2).Folders(Folder3)
messages = inbox.Items
for message in messages:
    print (message.Subject)
    filename = message.Subject
    message.SaveAS(Path+ "\\" + filename)
```